# How to wait for Meteor.user() and redirect if undefined from within the container?

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I want restrict non logged in users from viewing some pages in my app by redirecting them to the login page. I use react, flow router and the react komposer. The problem is, `Meteor.user()` first gives undefined and even-though the user is logged in, he gets re-directed into the login page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you need is [Meteor.loggingIn()](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loggingIn)

Before redirecting user you need to check if user is logging in like:

```
if(!Meteor.loggingIn() && !Meteor.userId()){
   //do redirect to login page
}
```